# Django REST FRAMEWORK + django admin data save

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am not able to save my rest API data to my another Django Project.

How I can populate another rest API data to my Django admin database ?

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in the database so I assume you want to transfer data to your new database.

You can do it in the following way.

1. First clear your new database - (here new is the name of your database, it is default but you can look it up in settings.py file and use that name)

   python manage.py flush --database=new
2. Export data from the old Database to a json file

   python manage.py dumpdata>data.json
3. Load Data into the new Database

   python manage.py loaddata data.json --database=new

You have the data in your new project database from your old database.